# How to play HTML5 video in Chrome web browser

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have yet to find any examples of a MP4 played using the  tag for HTML5. All the examples that I have found play using alternative code for Flash or other formats. In case my test video was not suitable I downloaded from a working example online but on my web page it does not play. The code is simple enough:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
  <source src="test/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I have tried my test page in the latest Chrome and Firefox web browsers, but each gives the same message... "No video with supported format and MimeType found".

Comment: Verify that your web server can serve mp4 files. If you are using apache put in your `Directory` directive: `AddType video/mp4 .mp4`

Comment: Could it be that the MimeType is not recognised by the server hosting the web page?

Comment: Check control panel in your web hosting and verify mp4 mime is enabled, Also you can try to open the mp4 directly by your browser typing in your address bar `http://yourwebserver/test/big_bunny.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox do indeed support HTML5 video and the video object code is correct. So if the test page is not working the next step is to check that the server displaying the test page does indeed support MP4 files.

If you are using Apache put in your Directory directive: 
AddType video/mp4 .mp4

If you are using Windows Server, instead of editing the site which can create an unwanted web.config file in your root, add the MimeType to the server. That way MP4 will be applied to all sites on the server:
Go to IIS Manager > Mime Types and add a new entry for

```
.mp4  video/mpeg
```

Click to save and then restart the server.